# Data restructuring from column wise to row wise

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

so during an interview I was challenged with a problem that I couldn't seem to figure out on dataset restructuring that I was hoping that someone could give me some guidance to!

Original:

[image: Original format]

Final:

[image]

The data is made up and is a simplified version of what was asked but the principle that I couldn't figure out is essentially the same.

Thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFram.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='state', columns='metric', values='values').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   state  gender ratio  population  temperature
0  texas          0.45      5000.0         60.0
```